# Store multiple routing attribute in variable or command ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using this `asp-route-{attribute}` multiple times. Is it possible to just put it in a variable and then use it on each action? Or any alternative would be greatly appreciated.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-info">
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-pageNumber="@Model.PageNumber" asp-route-pageSize="@ViewBag.PageSize" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.LanguageSortParam"
                   asp-route-filterName="@ViewBag.FilterStringName" asp-route-filterDesc;="@ViewBag.FilterStringDesc" asp-route-filterCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringCat"
                   asp-route-filterSubCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringSubCat" asp-route-filterModel="@ViewBag.FilterStringModel" asp-route-searchString="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter"
                   asp-route-selectedLanguage="@ViewBag.SelectedLanguage">Product Name</a>
                <form asp-action="Index" asp-route-pageSize="@ViewBag.PageSize" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.LanguageSortParam"
                      asp-route-filterName="@ViewBag.FilterStringName" asp-route-filterDesc;="@ViewBag.FilterStringDesc" asp-route-filterCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringCat"
                      asp-route-filterSubCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringSubCat" asp-route-filterModel="@ViewBag.FilterStringModel" asp-route-searchString="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter"
                      asp-route-selectedLanguage="@ViewBag.SelectedLanguage">
                    <input type="text" name="filterName" value="@ViewBag.FilterStringName" placeholder="Filter Product Name" asp-route-pageNumber="@Model.PageNumber" asp-route-pageSize="@ViewBag.PageSize" />
                </form>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-pageNumber="@Model.PageNumber" asp-route-pageSize="@ViewBag.PageSize" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.LanguageSortParam"
                   asp-route-filterName="@ViewBag.FilterStringName" asp-route-filterDesc;="@ViewBag.FilterStringDesc" asp-route-filterCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringCat"
                   asp-route-filterSubCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringSubCat" asp-route-filterModel="@ViewBag.FilterStringModel" asp-route-searchString="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter"
                   asp-route-selectedLanguage="@ViewBag.SelectedLanguage">Description</a>
                <form asp-action="Index" asp-route-pageSize="@ViewBag.PageSize" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewBag.LanguageSortParam"
                      asp-route-filterName="@ViewBag.FilterStringName" asp-route-filterDesc;="@ViewBag.FilterStringDesc" asp-route-filterCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringCat"
                      asp-route-filterSubCat="@ViewBag.FilterStringSubCat" asp-route-filterModel="@ViewBag.FilterStringModel" asp-route-searchString="@ViewBag.CurrentFilter"
                      asp-route-selectedLanguage="@ViewBag.SelectedLanguage">
                    <input type="text" name="filterDesc" value="@ViewBag.FilterStringDesc" placeholder="Filter Description" />
                </form>
            </th>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Desired output would be

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr class="table-info">
        <th>
            <a asp-action="Index" {MYVariable}>Product Name</a>
            <form asp-action="Index" {MYVariable}>
                <input type="text" name="filterName" value="@ViewBag.FilterStringName" placeholder="Filter Product Name" asp-route-pageNumber="@Model.PageNumber" asp-route-pageSize="@ViewBag.PageSize" />
            </form>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a asp-action="Index" {MYVariable}>Description</a>
            <form asp-action="Index" {MYVariable}>
                <input type="text" name="filterDesc" value="@ViewBag.FilterStringDesc" placeholder="Filter Description" />
            </form>
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: [asp-all-route-data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0#asp-all-route-data) ?

Comment: Your HTML looks pretty gnarly from all those route tag-helpers - at this point I think you should use custom `IUrlHelper` extensions instead - it will be a LOT simpler and easier to look at.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically transfer the attributes in asp-route-{attribute} from the backend?